# How to sum field when use group mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have documents mongoDB in behind.

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac06b6fb49124f4e5602817"),
    "status" : -1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-03-31T05:17:35.557Z")
}`

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac0b51cb08b6c0014d1d0c1"),
    "status" : 0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-01T10:31:56.199Z")
}`

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac0b538b08b6c0014d1d0c2"),
    "status" : 2,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-01T10:32:24.542Z")
}`

i used $group, $match, $sum and i only can return:

   `{
      _id: {
          month: 4,
          day: 1,
          year: 2018
      },
      count: 2
   }`

i want return:

   `{
      _id: {
          month: 4,
          day: 1,
          year: 2018
      },
      count : 2,
      countStatus0 : 1,
      countStatus2 : 1
   }`

i wish you help me...
Thank you so much.
Sorry my English is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
        month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" },
        status: "$status"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: "$_id.year",
        month: "$_id.month",
        day: "$_id.day"
      },
      count: { $sum: "$count" },
      statuses: { $push: { k: { $concat: ["status", {$substr:["$_id.status", 0, -1 ]}] }, v: "$count" } }  
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      count: 1,
      statuses: { $arrayToObject: "$statuses" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$statuses" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      statuses: 0
    }
  }
])
```

To get total sum and sums for each status you have to use `$group` twice. Each partial status can be converted to a pair of `k` and `v` where `key` is a dynamically generated string which is a concatenation of `status` and its value like `status0`, `status2`. Having those pairs you can use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to generate object fields from that array. Then you can use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to merge root with nested `statuses` object.

There is one trick here. Since MongoDB does not allow to concatenate string with double we have to use `$substr` on double to convert it to a string.